# X-Editable data binding not being parsed

Tags: knockout.js, x-editable

I am trying to get the X-editable working with knockout, following is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable();
        self.firstName = ko.observable();
        self.lastName = ko.observable();
        self.gender = ko.observable();

        self.genders = ko.observableArray();

        self.firstName = ko.observable('John');
        self.lastName = ko.observable('Doe');
        self.gender = ko.observable('Male');
        self.genders.push("Male");
        self.genders.push("Female");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    EditableManager.registerEditable();
    EditableManager.onSuccess = function (result) {

    };
```

This is my HTML,

```html
<span data-bind="editable: gender, editableOptions: {pk: id, options: genders, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'id'}"></span>
```

I am getting an exception

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "`editable: function (){return gender }`"
>   Message: Cannot read property '`length`' of undefined

I am new new to Knockout and x-editable, can anybody help on this, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the `new` in `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` it should be `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());`

Comment: Thanks nemesv, could you please post it as answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nemesv said I haven't new it up,

missing new in ko.applyBindings(viewModel); it should be ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());